# Does Google App Engine datastore.get(key) always return the same entity-object?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I’m looking to use the GAE Datastore directly, without using JDO/JPA.  I have a quick question:

Suppose I have this code:

```
Key key = getMyKey ();
Entity entity1 = dataStore.get (key);
Entity entity2 = dataStore.get (key);
```

Are `entity1` and `entity2` guaranteed to be the same object (i.e. `entity1 == entity2`), or can calls to `get` using the same key return different `Entity` instances?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Is the behavious different if the `get` operations are executed within a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetches will return different entity instances, even if there are no modifications between the two calls.

Comment: Using the example in my question, if I change the value of a property in `entity1`, will the changes show up in `entity2`, or only once the changes are committed?

Comment: No. An entity contains the data as it was when it was loaded from the datastore.